# Android Activity - Design on Server / Render on Client

Tags: android, user-interface, networking, dynamic

We have a Windows Mobile application which is being migrated to Android. It has a large-ish number of forms (around 150). Given the complexity of the rewrite ahead of us, I am looking for as many shortcuts as I can find :)

One of the options we are considering is as follows:

- Move all the .NET code from the WM application to a server component.
- Build or buy a component which runs on the Android device, but is a "mildly intelligent" interpreter.
- Code which would in the past have acted on the form directly, would now act on an intermediate object.
- This object would be passed back to the App which would render the output.
- The user sees the screen, scans or keys in data and a new request is made back to the server.

I'm thinking of something similar to a terminal emulator - except I want to be able to do something a bit more "intelligent". For example, screen types to:

- show some data in TextView objects
- display data in a table (something like a gridview) and allow selection of a row
- enter some text
- enter a date
- select from a drop-down list

Once the user completes the screen, the information entered is then sent back to the server for validation. The server will construct a new screen object and sent it back to the device.

Would anyone be able to point me in the direction of a pre-built component we could purchase? Is this possible?

Regards

Tim Muir

Comment: I think if your familiar with .net you should give xamarin a try, though I am not sure if it will hep or not

Comment: I believe Xamarin can do that for you. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into Xamarin. I have also found someone who has written code to convert Json into a UI. I'll check this out and update this if it is useful.